# Arduino restarts when writing SMS

Tags: sms, arduino, gsm

My Arduino (an Arduino Duemilanove clone) restarts when I try to respond to an SMS sent to the machine. Could this be a memory problem (it has only 2048 bytes RAM)?

I do not use that much for variables. Only sending works OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GSM library takes slightly less than 1000 bytes. Your serial port for debugging (assumming you use that), another 100 or so. So I guess you are running out of memory resulting in garbage to the debugging console or a restarting the Arduino.

You can check your memory with this code based on information I found in the Arduino Cookbook:

```
int memory_free()
{
    int free_value;
    if ((int)__brkval == 0)
        free_value = ((int)&free_value) - ((int)&__bss_end);
    else
        free_value = ((int)&free_value) - ((int)__brkval);
    return free_value;
}
```

In my experience, if that returns less than 150 bytes, you are in trouble.

Reduce the buffer size of the SMS to the minimum if you have that at the max of 160 characters. Once everything works, switch of logging anything to the debugging console (saved over 100 bytes) and increase the SMS size. You can actually do the debugging by sending an SMS, including memory status.

Comment: This seemed to be it, GSM library is memory hungry

Answer (score 2):

If your Arduino and GSM modem are on the same power supply, then you can try with a better power supply and repeat the test. You can also separate power supplies - one for Arduino and one for GSM modem and then repeat the test. If GSM modem is close to Arduino you can try to move it further away. If the reset still happens after all these measures, you have a software problem.

Comment: Things work fine in a program that only send or only receive, that would not work if it is a powersupply problem. And I would hate to unplug the GSM shield and have ca

Answer (score 2):

If the power and memory are OK, then your Arduino is rebooting because of an error in the program. Look for stray pointers.